# Use keyup function in multiple table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table that i can insert new row after click on a button. I would like to use a keyup function to make calcul between td values. My issue is the keyup function works for the first line, after I insert a new line the function affects the new line and previous line. How can I create the function to use it separately for each new row added ?

Thanks in advance.

```
    <button type="button" class="add-row" >Add</button>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Amount</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td>Result</td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='amount' contenteditable='true'></td>
<td class='price' contenteditable='true' onkeyup='calculfac()'></td>
<td class='result'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
//Add new row on click
$(".add-row").click(function(){
var markup = "<tr><td class='amount' contenteditable='true'></td><td class='price' contenteditable='true' onkeyup='calculfac()'></td><td class='result'></td></tr>";
$("table tbody").append(markup);
});

//Calcul

function calculfac() {
var amount= $('.amount').text();
var price= $('.price').text();
var mult = amount * price;
var result = Math.round(mult).toFixed(2);
$('.result').text(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there in your snippet. You can specify a parent when using creating jQuery selector: `$('.selector', parent)` where `parent` can be a jQuery object or another selector itself. See the snippet below:

```
function calculfac() {

  const parent = $(this).parent('tr');
  const amount = $('.amount', parent).text();
  const price = $('.price', parent).text();
  const result = Math.round(amount * price).toFixed(2);
  $('.result', parent).text(result);

}
```

Additionally I would remove `onkeyup="calculfac()"` from your elements and use a jQuery selector and pass in your function as the handler. This allows us to trigger the event on each editable zone instead of just the price. If we do not do this a user could set the price and later update the amount but the total would remain the same before the change. See the snippet below:

`$('tbody').on('keyup', '[contenteditable="true"]', calculfac);`

A key difference about the above snippet is we're using `.on`. Since the new `tr`'s are generated by your `click` handler a traditional selector of `tr [contenteditable="true"]` won't work as the new `tr` from your handler do not yet exist in the DOM at the time the selector is ran. `.on` allows you to filter a wider range of elements. So we're selecting `tbody` and on `keyup` of matching `contenteditable=true` elements we're passing the event to our `calculfac` function.

Here is the complete [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4b93zdp/)

Comment: Thank you Wild Beard but your fiddle is a 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: @Diasline strange, I updated the link to this one: https://jsfiddle.net/p4b93zdp/

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're working with classes. Your code can't recognize which class value should change. It will change all the values of all classnames.

You can fix it by using the `.each()` function. You want to change the contents of the `<td>` tags in almost each `<tr>` tag. Not every `<tr>` tag so we can use a class to tell which `<tr>` we mean. So, lets go:

**Step 1** - 
Add the class '.tr' at the  tags that have the  children that you want to change.

```
<tr class="tr">
```

**Step 2** - 
Add the '.tr' class to the 'Add new row' - function

```
//Add new row on click
$(".add-row").click(function(){

    var markup = "<tr class='tr'><td class='amount' contenteditable='true'></td><td class='price' contenteditable='true' onkeyup='calculfac()'></td><td class='result'></td></tr>"; //Add '.tr' class

    $("table tbody").append(markup);

});
```

**Step 3** -
Tell the classes that you want to get/change the values of them on each .tr class.

```
function calculfac() {

  $('.tr').each(function(){ //Each .tr class
        var amount= $('.amount', this).text(); //The .amount class of 'this' .tr class
        var price= $('.price', this).text(); //The .price class of 'this' .tr class
        var mult = amount * price;
        var result = Math.round(mult).toFixed(2);
        $('.result', this).text(result); //The .results class of 'this' .tr class

  });

}
```

**Example**

Check out the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z9qsyzr8/15/

Comment: It is unnecessary to run `calculfac` on every `tr` each time a single row is updated.

Comment: Thank you, but @WildBeard has a point. The function will run on each .tr class every time and that's not necessary since you only want to update the values of the price you change. Look at his answer below. Using the '.parent()' function will only select the parent <tr> tag.